# image stack population is slow in numpy

Tags: python, image, numpy

I am reading stack of separate tiff's into single 3D array via numpy/python. When files are just read and plugged into some variable, speed scales linearly with number of files, for example, loading 100 files takes 0.2s, loading 1000 files takes 2.46s and so on.

However, when I try to create a 3D stack out of those files, using *dstack()* time starts to scale non-linearly, e.g. 0.21 sec for 10 files, 5.39sec for 100 files and so on.

I realize that slow-down is caused by some magic behind dstack(). What is the proper and fastest way to create 3D stacks from set of image files?

If I don't use dtack(), but pre-create 3D array an then populate it, script is running faster, but still scales non-linearly (0.2s for 10, 2.2s for 100, 40s for 1000 images)
Code for this case:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import time
import random

def toc(t):
    return time.time() - t

i_max = 1000
t = time.time()
for i in range(0,i_max):
    fname = r"..\Pos0\img_"+("%09d"%i)+"_Default_000.tif"
    im = np.array(Image.open(fname))
    if i>0:
        stack[:,:,i] = im
    else:
        s = im.shape
        stack = np.empty((s[0],s[1],i_max))
        stack[:,:,0] = im
print toc(t)
```

PS: Python 2.7.8 Anaconda 2.1, Intel i5 @ 32GB RAM, reading from 4-striped HDDs

Comment: How big (MB) is each image? If you are exceeding the amount of available *free* RAM, that would explain the non-linear increase from 100 to 1000 images as some objects will need to be stored on the swap-memory. The increase from 10 to 100 is linear and your guess about not preallocating is correct.

Comment: Single tiff is <2MB. I am of course way below filling up RAM and going into swap

Comment: Besides the indexing, if you need to load same image sequence often, it is worth first converting it to one big file with raw bytes. A convertion util, like `Imagemagick`, can do it and attempts to use multicore, so would be faster than converting with python script, if  speed is important.

Comment: thing is, I acquire images with MicroManager, so I technically can have single file-stack in first place. Is it going to be better, I have >27k z-slices (or time points, that is 3D image)? I also would like to be able to cut substacks from those 27k frames

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve this problem by changing the order of your indexing, making the image index first.  Like this:

```
i_max = 1000
sx, sy = 1000,1000
t = time.time()
for i in range(0,i_max):
    im = np.ones((sx,sy))
    if i>0:
        #stack[:,:,i] = im
        stack[i,:,:] = im
    else:
        #stack = np.empty((sx,sy,i_max))
        #stack[:,:,0] = im
        stack = np.empty((i_max, sx, sy))
        stack[0,:,:] = im
print toc(t)
```

The times I get are:

```
4.44851183891   # original order, i_max = 100
118.510767937   # original order, i_max = 1000

1.78239989281   # modified order, i_max = 100
23.4904351234   # modified order, i_max = 1000
```

I think the reason for this is that the data is not handled bit-by-bit, but in chunks of fixed size, regardless of how much data in each chunk is actually being used.  With your original order, the chunks were not being used efficiently.  For example, see the first few minutes of this video: https://vimeo.com/97337258  That is, it's not about RAM but CPU cache.

Comment: Good call on the memory-ordering.  Alternately, initializing the array as fortran-ordered and using the OP's original indexing style should solve the same problem and has the advantage of keeping the indices in a more logical order.

Comment: This seems like an insane solution. As you can imagine, I do not care about indexing, (t,x,y) is as good as (y,t,x) or anything else.

Comment: I greatly appreciate help. Changing indexing or fortran-ordering solves the problem, with order='F' being ~2x slower. Didn't know it was so simple. However, is there an industry-wide standard for compiling 3D stacks from separate image files, or this is it?

Comment: This isn't an 'image' specific issue.  It's just an `numpy` array construction one.  This is one way.  `np.array([make_array(i) for i  in range(n)])` is another, as is it's equivalent using list appends.  At least in this case, index assignment is the faster approach.

Comment: @aandreev: I don't think there are "industry-wide standards".  Image stacking is not uncommon though, eg, in specialties where the images are naturally stacked, like confocal microscopy (where they're known as "z stacks").  Rather than a standard, I think people generally follow the guideline to put data points that they want to read together close together.  So if you collect an image stack, but then want to process perpendicular planes, it can makes sense to rotate the stack (which is why I don't do Fortran ordering, so my ordering can be mailable and remain nonconfusing).